# Evaluation of type for auto in C++0X

Tags: c++, c++11

I am playing around with the auto feature in the C++0X standard but I am confused how the decision of the type is made. Consider the following code.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::f" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::f" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* dp = new Derived;
    auto b1 = *dp;
    auto& b2 = *dp;
    std::cout << typeid(b1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(b2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

It will print Base and Derived.
But why is the `auto&`evaluated to a ref to Derived and not to a ref to Base?
Even worse changing the code to this:

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived : public Base{};

int main()
{
    Base* dp = new Derived;
    auto b1 = *dp;
    auto& b2 = *dp;
    std::cout << typeid(b1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(b2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

returns Base for both types. So why is the type depended on the virtual functions?
The compiler I am using is VS2010.
Can anyone give me a hint where I can find the definition of this behavior in the standard?

Comment: "But why is the auto& evaluated to a ref to Derived and not to a ref to Base?" Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Not a bug -- typeid(obj) looks at the vtable, not the declared type.  in b2's case, it still has the Derived vtable.

Comment: @Cory: more of a misunderstanding on @mkaes side. It resolves to `Base&`, not `Derived&`, it is just that the operation he is interpreting incorrectly the results of the test (well, in fact the problem is that the test is inconclusive for this particular case, a more interesting test would be creating two overloads of a function, one taking `Base&`, the other `Derived&` and verifying which of them is being called)

Comment: I sort of understand the first set but the last line returning Base baffles me. - ok, forgot about virtuals again. See David's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case with virtual function(s):

```
auto b1 = *dp;
auto& b2 = *dp;
```

First line causes [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) which means `b1` is an object of type`Base`, so it prints `Base`. And the second line is creating an object of type `Base&` which is a reference to the *actual* object pointed to by `dp`. The actual object is of type `Derived`. Hence it prints `Derived`.

The second line is equivalent to the following:

```
Base & b = *dp; //this is also a reference to the actual object
std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
```

What will it print? `Base`? No. This will print `Derived`. See this yourself:

- http://www.ideone.com/9IjPc

---

Now the second case : when you don't have virtual function in `Base` then `dp` points to subobject of object created with `new`

```
Base* dp = new Derived; //dp gets subobject
```

That is why you get `Base` even with `auto &` because `dp` is not a polymorphic object anymore.

Comment: Is it defined when an object gets polymorphic. I assume as soon as it has a vtable. So adding a virtual function or Dtor makes the object virtual. But are there any other ways?

Comment: @mkaes: Polymorphic class means a class with virtual function(s), and object of such class is called is called polymorphic object, which can be a *reference* or *pointer*.

Answer (score 11):

`auto` in both contexts is yielding `Base`, not derived. In the first case you are slicing the object (copy at the parent level) while in the second case, because it is a reference, you get a `Base&` to the actual `Derived` object. That means that all virtual function calls will be dispatched to the final overrider at the `Derived` level.

The `typeid` operator has different behavior for polymorphic types than for non-polymorphic ones. If applied to a reference to a polymorphic type it will perform a type check at runtime and yield the type of the actual object. If it is applied to an object or to a reference to a non-polymorphic type it will be resolved at compile time to the static type of the object or reference.

To verify what the `auto` is inferring, you can use a slightly different test:

```
void test( Base& ) { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
void test( Derived& ) { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
```

Then call the function and see what type it is resolving to. I would expect the compiler to pick the first overload, as `auto& a = *dp;` should be equivalent to `Base& a = *dp;`

Comment: There are no virtual function calls in the examples posted. The `f()` functions are never called.

Comment: @Mat: They don't have to be called, they only have to be defined for `typeid()` to become, effectively, a virtual call.

Comment: @DeadMG: thanks for the clarification, hadn't thought about it that way.

Comment: @Mat: the decision of how `typeid` check is performed is based on the type, not on the operations applied to it. If the type has virtual functions, and the argument to `typeid` is a reference, then it will perform the test at runtime. Otherwise it will resolve the type at compile time. *Existence* of the virtual function matters, while *calls* to those functions have no effect. Also not that technically (i.e. according to the standard) non-pure virtual functions are *used* even if the code does not call them.

Answer (score 2):

The information for the typeid comes from the vtable -- so it uses the actual type of the object, not what the auto might be.  In the b1 case, dp got sliced down to a Base, so the vtable is now a Base one.  In b2's case, there was no slicing, so it's vtable is the original.

For the second question, RTTI is only available for polymorphic classes (at least one virtual method).  This is because the information is only kept if you have a vtable -- allowing simple Plain-old-data objects to be the right size.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a reference to derived, it's a reference to Base. When you have a polymorphic object, then `typeid()` effectively becomes a virtual call and returns the most derived type. The reason that your second test set returns base both times is because there are no virtual functions, so `typeid()` returns the static type of the object, which is `Base`.

In other words, it doesn't become a reference to derived, you're just printing out the name wrong. You would have to do `typeid(decltype(b2)).name()` to be sure that you're looking at the name of the static type of the object.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` works exactly (but see below) as if you take the whole auto'ed variable type and use it as the type of a function template parameter type. All `auto` occurrences in the type are replaced by a template parameter. So if you used `auto&` as the auto'ed variable type, the function template's parameter type becomes

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&); // auto& -> T&
```

Now let the variable initializer be the argument in a call `f(initializer)`. The type of the function parameter you get will be the type of the auto'ed variable. For example if you use `auto&` as the type like above, then `f` will become a function template with parameter type `T&`. If the initializer is a `Base` expression, then the variable ends up having type `Base&`, because that will be the deduced parameter type for the call `f(a_Base_argument)`.

So, using `auto` as the auto'ed variable type will use a function template with parameter type `T` behind the scenes. Calling `f(a_Base_argument)` will end up with the parameter type `Base`. This is not a reference to another object anymore, but a new `Base` variable.

The above way to get the auto'ed type is true for the vast majority of cases, but C++0x has a special case for initializers of the form `{ a, b, c }` (i.e with variable initializers that are braced lists). In your case you don't have such an initializer, so I have ignored that special case.

The reason why in one of your cases `Derived` instead of `Base` is explained by other answers. To get what you were looking for using `typeid`, you can first get the declared type of the variable (using `decltype`), and then pass that as a type to `typeid` as in

```
typeid(decltype(b2)).name()
```